# Simple error checking in file output

Tags: c++

So I have a question regarding the use of ofstream in a while loop. Say I had an array of size `X` and I wanted to loop though that array and output the items to file. Would the following code be sufficent for error checking? If so (or not so) why?

```
char arr[X];
ofstream fout("out.txt");
for(int i=0;i<X;i++)
{
     while(!(fout<<arr[i]){}
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to close your stream after for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing `char`s there aren't too many things which can go wrong. The only error which may occur is that the stream's `std::streambuf` reports an error in `overflow()`. This adequately tested by your test. That said, successfully buffering characters doesn't mean that writing the buffer will be successful. To test for a successful write you'll also need to test if `fout.close()` is successful! The implicit `close()` in the destructor will just swallow any errors.

Note, however, that once the stream went into failure state it would stop doing anything useful until `clear()` is called on the stream. Put differently, if there is an error while writing to the stream, you'll just end up with an infinite loop. Even with a call to `clear()` I wouldn't expect that an underlying stream buffer would do anything different, i.e., I would expect it to just fail again. That is, if you really care about these errors you'll need to come up with a better error handling strategy than "try again"!

Comment: so adding a fout.close() after the while loop is necessary for full buffer handling?

Comment: Adding `fout.close()` _and_ checking its result is necessary if you want to know that the buffer has successfully been delivered to the OS.